# Angular 6 - changing the variable but doesn't refresh the view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, binding

I have an array variable, which contains objects, just like this:

```
[{name: 'Name 1', price: '10$'}, {name: 'Name 2', price: '20$'}, ...]
```

I have a view, which prints out the list of the products, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   {{item.name}} - {{item.price}}
</div>
```

This is just an example but the 'model' of the problem is the same:

If I change the 'items' array from the code (for example because an external event occured) the variable value is changes, but the view won't refreshed :(.

How can I make this work?

Edit:

changeArray() includes only one line:

`changeArray(items) : void{
    this.items = items;
}`

Maybe the problem is that, I call this method of A, from an another component?
So, in component 'B', I have a line just like this:

`a.changeArray(items);`

Comment: Show us how the `items` array is modified in your code.

Comment: I have a component 'A', and I call A.changeArray() function from component 'B'. The variable a.items will be changes, but the view won't updating.

Comment: Include in the question the code of `changeArray()`.

Comment: Can you post the codes of your components or at least the codes of your `changeArray()` function so we can know what's the issue in there?

Comment: what's the relationship between components? p-c or siblings?

Comment: B component imports A component, 'A' component reference variable defined at the B components constructor. Both components are defined/imported at the same modul.

Comment: How did you refer component A in B's constructor? Please show the relevant sections of your code for easier debugging

Comment: I strongly suggest you use inputs and outputs. Calling a method from a child is not something I recommend. It creates all kinds of complexities and side effects. That aside, on what kind of event do you call the method `changeArray`?

Answer (score 9):

One way to force refresh the list is to use the spread operator `...`

So after you have updated your (say) `items` property in your component, do this,

```
// after items are updated logic, and assuming it is an array,
this.items = [...this.items];
```

this should refresh your list.

If you provide your entire code to replicate the problem, this force change approach may be fine tuned.

UPDATE:

Based on your comments,

update the `changeArray()` to this,

```
changeArray(items) : void{
  this.items = [...items];
}
```

UPDATE2:

If the above doesn't work, try this too,

in the component where `changeArray()` is defined, add this to the `constructor` and import `ChangeDetectorRef` as well,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(cRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changeArray(items) : void{
  this.items = [...items];
  this.cRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I don't think a force update is a good idea when this issue can be avoided when the array manipulation is done properly.

Comment: @RyanTsui agree, but only if the logic is provided. I have updated my answer with the conditional comments in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: How are your 2 components related. May be shed a bit more light on their relationship. Or make a reproducable code?

Comment: Okay, theoretical question: If I call a method of  A component, from an another component, the method's 'this' variable is the same as when I call that method from the component A itself?

Comment: it depends on how you refer that component from within the other component. It will be easier if you show your code.

Answer (score 6):

Angular expects arrays to be immutable. You cannot alter the contents of the array, but need to create a new one (change the reference).

As an example use `concat` which returns a new array instead of `push` to add elements.

Comment: I dont know why not working :( But I do the followings:

I have a component 'A', and I call A.changeArray() function from component 'B'. The variable a.items will be changes, but the view won't updating.